# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication

I've used `GoogleApiClient` object, inherited `ConnectionCallbacks` interface and calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context context, String accountName, String scope)` from two different methods.
1. overriden `onConnected()` method of `ConnectionCallbacks` interface.

2. `onClick()` method of button.

In both of these I am getting different response of `getToken()` method.

1. while calling from **onConnected**() method: it throws error like: java.lang.**IllegalStateException**: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock.
2. In case while calling from **onClick()** method, **it works fine!!!**

What is difference between these 2 calls? `onClick()` executes in main thread. Right?

onClick() method:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getGoogleToken();
}
```

onConnected() method:

```java
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
     getGoogleToken();
 }
```

getGoogleToken() method:

```java
private void getGoogleToken() {
    try {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        //Retrieve the google token
        String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accounts[0].name, PRIVATE_KEY); // This line generates error.

        // ...

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is stackTrace:

```
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzcy(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at num.app.gpluslogin.MainActivity.getGoogleToken(MainActivity.java:274)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at num.app.gpluslogin.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:207)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg.zzi(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.700 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.zzpi(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.701 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.onConnected(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.701 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi.onConnected(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.701 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlz.onConnected(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqv(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqx(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-25 17:53:02.702 23235-23235/num.app.gpluslogin W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-25 17:53:09.358 1587-1605/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
```

Comment: are you doing for google signup?

Comment: Yes. I am doing that.

Comment: I'm curious to know why / how you came to use GoogleAuthUtil instead of the actual Google Sign-In SDK? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/  ... we are going to deprecate GoogleAuthUtil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the below code block in a background thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

     android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        //Your code
try {

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
        Account[] accounts =  am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        //Retrieve the google token
        String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accounts[0].name, PRIVATE_KEY); // This line generates error.
        .......
        .....
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
          ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
}).start();
```

Comment: @pratik03  try replacing thread with IntentService for improvement over the above code